# Installing Joomla with nobody:nobody user/group (CentOS/cPanel)

Tags: linux, access-control, file-access, centos, joomla

If you are installing Joomla via cPanel's File Manager to your mywebsite.com *(user mywebsite)* account, you will upload the package to your server and extract the archive. All files will have the user and group according to your account **mywebsite:mywebsite**. You will have to change around three dozen directories and files and make them writable: http://goo.gl/EYjIPW and you can go ahead with the installation. All files created during the installation and later, using the Joomla platform will have the user and group **nobody:nobody**.

If you chown all extracted files to **nobody:nobody**, prior to installation, you won't have to bother about making the above-mentioned directories writable plus more than likely you will not run into any "Permission denied" errors later (changing the owner can be done after the installation as well).

**The question**, do you know any drawbacks of having the files owned by **nobody:nobody**? What are the pros and cons? And what about the files that are created by Joomla during and after the installation, these are by default owned by **nobody:nobody**.

Answer (score 1):

Some daemons traditionally use `nobody`, so that if they are comprimised, the access they have is limited.  If you start assigning files to the `nobody` user, then if you do have a daemon running as that user, and it was comprimised in some way, then the attacker could potentially gain access to the files.  Given that the files are a website, and Joomla configuration files contain the database details in plaintext, this could be pretty disastrous for you.

It doesn't seem like a good idea to me, even if daemons that run as `nobody` are rarer nowadays - the idea of user per daemon allows for greater security against daemons communicating with each other spuriously.

Comment: Thank you @Owen, this is the reason I asked, doesn't seem right to me to have all files under the nobody user, server-wide, all accounts. However, all files created by Joomla on a cPanel server (default settings) are owned by nobody:nobody and configuration.php is created by Joomla, right after the installation. Meaning, all configuration.php files on a server (that may host 100+ Joomla websites) are owned by nobody. Does it make any sense to chown at least these files to owninguser:owninguser ?